# How would I make my image go to the next image onclick while fading using javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I've seen a question of this nature before on SO but not quite exactly what I'm looking for.

Upon the user clicking on an image, I want it to have a fade effect as it moves on to the next image.  Once the next image is displayed, I want it to, again, have a fade effect as it moves onto the next image.  So and so forth.

My current code below immediately upon onclick goes from img-1 (first image) to the img-2 but img-2 fades and never reaches img-3.

What am I doing wrong and how can I rectify this?

```
let theImage = document.getElementById('the-image');

let index = {
    "img-1" : "https://www.folkdeal.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/d/fd-ea10150-1.jpg",
    "img-2" : "http://image.en.yibada.com/data/images/full/66771/the-legend-of-zelda-japanese-hepburn-zeruda-no-densetsu-is-a-high-fantasy-action-adventure-video-game-series-created-by-japanese-game-designers-shigeru-miyamoto-and-takashi-tezuka.png",
    "img-3" : "https://www.geekisus.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/01_1575-11-400x400.jpg"
};

let clickedImage = () => {
    if(theImage.src === index["img-1"]) {
        theImage.src = index["img-2"];
        let op = 1;  // initial opacity
        let timer = setInterval(() => {
            if (op <= 0.1){
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
            theImage.style.opacity = op;
            op -= 0.1;
        }, 100);
    }

    else if(theImage.src === index["img-2"]) {
        theImage.src = index["img-3"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Another approach to consider: store the image names in an array. Maintain a 'currentIndex' that will vary between 0 and 2. When you fade an image, increment the index, if it's too big, zero it. Now, grab your next image as being the one pointed to by the index. Repeat ad nauseum. Array indices are not so special - using the object with keys (img-1, img-2, img-3) is a bit of a pain in the ass to write, read and alter.. ;) I'd murder you if you asked me to make the (your) code work with 100 images - with a 'curIndex' type method - it's no more complex to do 1,000,000 images than it is to do 2.

Comment: @enhzflep I get where you're coming from sort of, thanks.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. Another avenue to consider is using CSS animation to do the fading. At the end of a time-period, a class could be added to the image, which could then trigger a css animation. I never use the things and haven't got the hang of em yet. This page discusses them: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp And if you look at the css file they're using, there's lots of css animation in there. Specifically, here's for the fading one: `.w3-animate-fading{animation:fading 10s infinite}@keyframes fading{0%{opacity:0}50%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0}}`

Comment: @enhzflep yeah I'm aware of the CSS way :).  I'm just trying to up my JS skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im giving you a solution, you forgot to reset opacity. i improved it to a more dynamic aproach:

```
let index = [
  "https://www.folkdeal.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/d/fd-ea10150-1.jpg",
  "http://image.en.yibada.com/data/images/full/66771/the-legend-of-zelda-japanese-hepburn-zeruda-no-densetsu-is-a-high-fantasy-action-adventure-video-game-series-created-by-japanese-game-designers-shigeru-miyamoto-and-takashi-tezuka.png",
  "https://www.geekisus.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/01_1575-11-400x400.jpg"
];
let theImage = document.getElementById('the-image');

//preload all except first
for (let i = index.length -1; i > 0; i--) {
  let img = new Image();
      img.src = index[i];
}
theImage.src = index[0];
var op = 1;  // initial opacity
let imageId = 0;
let clickedImage = () => {
  //stat animation if opacity is 1
  if (op == 1) {
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (op <= 0.1) {
        //load the next image
        imageId = (1 + imageId) % index.length;
        theImage.src = index[imageId];
        //reset opacity
        theImage.style.opacity = op = 1;
        clearInterval(timer);
      } else {
        op -= 0.1;
        theImage.style.opacity = op;
      }
    }, 100);
  }
}
```